# Unable to upload image using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, webdriver

I need to upload the image using Selenium Web driver with Java.
I have tried following ways:

1. sendkeys() : it isn't working [xpath used: //input[@id='brandingContent_AddImage']]
2. Robot class: works only in local but stops working in the remote and parallel execution.
3. Sikuli : working only if the test execution screen is in focus. Doesn't work in parallel execution.
4. AutoIT : not tried yet.

Need a way that is able to upload the image successfully and also works in parallel execution.
Thanks in advance..!!

below is the HTML Snippet:[HTML IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Udfw.png)

```html
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new col-md-4 pl-1 " data-provides="fileinput">                            <div class="w-100 float-left">                                <div class="ctn_img_upload pull-left" id="uploadView_brandingContent_AddImage" xpath="1">                                    <div class="ad_file">                                        <span class="flaticon-plus"></span>                                        <input type="hidden" value="" name=""><input autocomplete="off" type="button" data-minsize="300x600" data-c="" data-placeholder="brandingContent_AddImage" id="brandingContent_AddImage" class="browse-img fileupload-skin" onclick="brandingViewGenerator.uploadImage(event)" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: -8px;right: 0;bottom: 0;width: 74px;height: 66px;">                                        <label class="fileupload-skin-label" for="editpanel_native_1" id="">Upload</label>                                    </div>                                </div>                                <div class="edit-image" id="branding_image_preview_brandingContent_AddImage" style="display:none">                                    <img id="imageBlock_brandingContent_AddImage" src="">                                    <input class="delete1 bg-blue-flamingo" type="button" onclick="brandingViewGenerator.editImage(event)" id="edit_brandingContent_AddImage">                                   <input class="update bg-blue" type="button" id="upload_brandingContent_AddImage" data-minsize="300x600" onclick="brandingViewGenerator.uploadImage(event)">                                </div>                            </div>                            <br clear="all">                            <input type="hidden" name="centerStrech" value="center">                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is if you see `//input[@type='file']` in **HTMLDOM** then you can use it with

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("full path of the file which is to be uploaded");
```

Comment: Since the type of this element is 'button' sendkeys isn't working.

Comment: do you see `//input[@type='file']` in entire HTMLDOM ?

Comment: Nopes. I've also added an image of the Html snippet

Comment: yes however that snippet does not have entire HTML, can you check in HTMLDOM using browser inspect ?